Unexpected Interaction between fontspec, NFSSFamily and LetterSpace
For a project, we need to letter space some phrases in capital letters. Since we want it to work in xelatex as well, we cannot use microtype. But we should be able to use a local font spec setting to do that. This example works just fine.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\FooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\begin{document}
\FooFont

FooBar { \addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30} FooBar } FooBar
\end{document}


However, when I use it in my project things literally blow up. After working it for a bit, it seems to come down to the added use of the NFSSFamily config key.
To make the examples a bit simpler, consider this example, with two texts, each in their own group. Where we can use * and + to add a font size and letter spacing respectively.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\FooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
%[NFSSFamily = Foo,]
% * = add font size, + = add letter space
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{ s t+ }
{%
  \begingroup
  \noindent%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fontsize{15bp}{15bp}\selectfont}%
  \FooFont%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}}%
  FooBar%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\begin{document}
\Test+

\Test
\end{document}


Which gives the expected output similar to the above. Changing the font size does not change anything.
Now try this
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\FooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
[ NFSSFamily = Foo, ]
% * = add font size, + = add letter space
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{ s t+ }
{%
  \begingroup
  \noindent%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fontsize{15bp}{15bp}\selectfont}%
  \FooFont%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}}%
  FooBar%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\begin{document}
\Test+

\Test
\end{document}

Which gives

so now the letter space is global?
If we also change the fontsize (the starred \Test)
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\FooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
[ NFSSFamily = Foo, ]
% * = add font size, + = add letter space
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{ s t+ }
{%
  \begingroup
  \noindent%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fontsize{15bp}{15bp}\selectfont}%
  \FooFont%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}}%
  FooBar%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\begin{document}
\Test*+

\Test
\end{document}

Then there is no letter space in the first, but it is still there in the second one

If we move the font sizing until after \addfontfeature then both are letter spaced.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\FooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
[ NFSSFamily = Foo, ]
% * = add font size, + = add letter space
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{ s t+ }
{%
  \begingroup
  \noindent%
  \FooFont%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}}%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fontsize{15bp}{15bp}\selectfont}%
  FooBar%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\begin{document}
\Test*+

\Test
\end{document}


Can anyone explain what it going on here? Is it simply down to the imposibility to have local font features when NFSSFamily is added?
For my project, I'll just keep using the soul package. It seems to work ok.

@cfr that still does not explain why it happens in these combinations.

it's because each time you tell it to define nfss font family Foo. letter-spacing requires a new family, so you are redefining it each time. font size is part of the standard dimensions and separate from family, but letter-spacing is not a distinct dimension so fontspec deals with it by defining an additional family. if you tell it to use the name of an existing family, it isn't additional.

I put some explanation below as it is too long for a comment. but I don't know why the first HooBar is not letter-spaced.

[Partial explanation - will delete later.]
Under the hood, fontspec always creates an NFSS family. To see what happens, we can trace the creation of fonts in the log.
\newfontfamily\FooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}

When fontspec adds a font feature to a family declared without specifying the NFSS family, it creates a family name based on-the-fly. For example, here it uses TeXGyreHeros(0):
Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'TeXGyreHeros(0)' created for font 'TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros' with options [].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"

If you specify the family, it uses it as expected.
    \newfontfamily\GooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
    [ NFSSFamily = Goo, ]
    \newfontfamily\HooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
    [ NFSSFamily = Hoo, ]    
    \newfontfamily\IooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
    [ NFSSFamily = Ioo, ]

produces
Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'Goo' created for font 'TeX Gyre Heros'
(fontspec)             with options [NFSSFamily = Goo].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"


Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'Hoo' created for font 'TeX Gyre Heros'
(fontspec)             with options [NFSSFamily = Hoo].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"


Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'Ioo' created for font 'TeX Gyre Heros'
(fontspec)             with options [NFSSFamily = Ioo].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+smcp;"

as we'd expect.
Now consider
    Test:
    
    \Test+
    
    \Test
    
    \Test*+
    
    \Test

This produces the following
Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'TeXGyreHeros(1)' created for font 'TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre Heros' with options [LetterSpace=30].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;+smcp;"

Inserting `luaotfload.letterspace' in `pre_linebreak_filter'.
Inserting `luaotfload.letterspace' in `hpack_filter'.

Note that this uses a different family name, TeXGyreHeros(1).
But if you specify that it should use a particular family name, it uses that name. Hence,
    G:
    
    \TestG+
    
    \TestG
    
    \TestG*+
    
    \TestG

produces
Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'Goo' created for font 'TeX Gyre Heros'
(fontspec)             with options [NFSSFamily = Goo,LetterSpace=30].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;+smcp;"

Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'Goo' created for font 'TeX Gyre Heros'
(fontspec)             with options [NFSSFamily =
(fontspec)             Goo,LetterSpace=30,LetterSpace=30].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;letterspace=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;letterspace=30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;letterspace=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;letterspace=30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;letterspace=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;letterspace=30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;letterspace=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;letterspace=30;+smcp;"

Note that it uses the same family name, Goo, because that's what your code told it to do. That's just like any other declaration of a font family in NFSS: it overwrites any existing definition.
Note, too, that it duplicates letterspacing=30 on each invocation because each time, it is told to add to the features.
However, a change of font size doesn't require a new family because that's within the ordinary parameters of font changes, so there is a difference between adding letter-spacing to a font and scaling it. So order matters.
H:

\TestH*+

\TestH

I:

\TestI*+

\TestI

produces
Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'Hoo' created for font 'TeX Gyre Heros'
(fontspec)             with options [NFSSFamily = Hoo,LetterSpace=30].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;+smcp;"

(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;+smcp;"


Package fontspec Info:
(fontspec)             Font family 'Ioo' created for font 'TeX Gyre Heros'
(fontspec)             with options [NFSSFamily = Ioo,LetterSpace=30].
(fontspec)
(fontspec)              This font family consists of the following NFSS
(fontspec)             series/shapes:
(fontspec)
(fontspec)             - 'normal' (m/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;"
(fontspec)             - 'small caps'  (m/sc) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=30
;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold' (b/n) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold small caps'  (b/sc) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/B:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic' (m/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;"
(fontspec)             - 'italic small caps'  (m/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/I:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace=
30;+smcp;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic' (b/it) with NFSS spec.: <->"name:TeX
(fontspec)             Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;"
(fontspec)             - 'bold italic small caps'  (b/scit) with NFSS spec.:
(fontspec)             <->"name:TeX Gyre
(fontspec)             Heros/BI:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;letterspace
=30;+smcp;"

If you add letter-spacing, you change the definition of the font family and it affects all subsequent usage. Changing font size just changes the font size.
But I'm not sure why the letter-spacing is not effective in the Hoo case until the next invocation of the family. It makes perfect sense it affects the second Hoo line, but I'm not sure why it does not also affect the first.
Test file:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{fonttable}
\usepackage{tracefnt}% infoshow is default; debugshow traces maths fonts, too
\newfontfamily\FooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
%[NFSSFamily = Foo,]
% * = add font size, + = add letter space
\NewDocumentCommand\Test{ s t+ }
{%
  \begingroup
\NewDocumentCommand\foobear{}{Arth}
\foobear
  \noindent%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fontsize{15bp}{15bp}\selectfont}%
  \FooFont%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}}%
  FooBar%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\newfontfamily\GooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
[ NFSSFamily = Goo, ]
% * = add font size, + = add letter space
\NewDocumentCommand\TestG{ s t+ }
{%
  \begingroup
  \noindent%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fontsize{15bp}{15bp}\selectfont}%
  \GooFont%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}}%
  GooBar%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\newfontfamily\HooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
[ NFSSFamily = Hoo, ]
% * = add font size, + = add letter space
\NewDocumentCommand\TestH{ s t+ }
{%
  \begingroup
  \noindent%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fontsize{15bp}{15bp}\selectfont}%
  \HooFont%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}}%
  HooBar%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\newfontfamily\IooFont{TeX Gyre Heros}
[ NFSSFamily = Ioo, ]
% * = add font size, + = add letter space
\NewDocumentCommand\TestI{ s t+ }
{%
  \begingroup
  \noindent%
  \IooFont%
  \IfBooleanT{#2}{\addfontfeature{LetterSpace=30}}%
  \IfBooleanT{#1}{\fontsize{15bp}{15bp}\selectfont}%
  IooBar%
  \endgroup
  \par
}
\begin{document}
Test:

\Test+

\Test

\Test*+

\Test

G:

\TestG+

\TestG

\TestG*+

\TestG

H:

\TestH*+

\TestH

I:

\TestI*+

\TestI

\end{document}

